# QTabBar keep last tab fixed

Tags: c++, qt, qtabwidget, qtabbar

I added a "new tab" button to the right tab using the QTabWidget [addTab](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtabwidget.html#addTab) method.

On multiple tabs a truncated tab bar shown and hides the last tab.

I tried to set the  `QTabBar::setUsesScrollButtons(false);`

But the TabWidget width get expanded.

How can I keep the last tab fixed?